# sklearn: Evaluating LinearSVC's AUC

Tags: scikit-learn, svm, libsvm, liblinear

I know that one would evaluate the AUC of `sklearn.svm.SVC` by passing in the `probability=True` option into the constructor, and having the SVM predict probabilities, but I'm not sure how to evaluate `sklearn.svm.LinearSVC`'s AUC. Does anyone have any idea how?

I'd like to use `LinearSVC` over `SVC` because `LinearSVC` seems to train faster on data with many attributes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the CalibratedClassifierCV class to extract the probabilities. Here is an [example with code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40206891/3899180).

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.calibration import CalibratedClassifierCV
from sklearn import datasets

#Load iris dataset
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2] # Using only two features
y = iris.target      #3 classes: 0, 1, 2

linear_svc = LinearSVC()     #The base estimator

# This is the calibrated classifier which can give probabilistic classifier
calibrated_svc = CalibratedClassifierCV(linear_svc,
                                        method='sigmoid',  #sigmoid will use Platt's scaling. Refer to documentation for other methods.
                                        cv=3) 
calibrated_svc.fit(X, y)


# predict
prediction_data = [[2.3, 5],
                   [4, 7]]
predicted_probs = calibrated_svc.predict_proba(prediction_data)  #important to use predict_proba
print predicted_probs
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's not possible.
https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/4820